# After beginning a sentence with "The question is," should the question itself use inverted or straight syntax?

Tags: expressions

After beginning a sentence with "The question is," should the question itself use inverted or straight syntax?

> - The question is, when is it worth doing, and when is it not?
> - The question is when it is worth doing, and when it is not."

Comment: Either is understood. It is more common to invert to keep it in a question form.

Comment: I would appreciate it if downvoters would provide some justification for the downvote.

Comment: I dunno, it wasn't me. Don't worry about it. I thought it was a good question. I'll offset one vote. Maybe others will also.

Answer (score 2):

Both your variants are acceptable. The comma you included immediately after "The question is" in the first variant turns your question into a *direct question* (which therefore requires a question mark and the inverted syntax).

The second variant does not include the comma; the result is a version of the question which has the format of *reported speech,* and therefore does not require a question mark.

My only quibble is that "worth to do it" is not idiomatic English, and would be better phrased as "worth doing [it]". (The 'it' enclosed in square brackets is optional.)

Comment: Sometimes comments (esp the last part of your answer) are useful.

Comment: My quibble would be that the comma ought really to be a colon. But it's a minor quibble.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - Either a comma or a colon would be considered acceptable by most native speakers.

Comment: With direct speech / quote structures, a colon, a comma or zero punctuation are nowadays acceptable as introductory punctuation. The rider is that they're not always equally appropriate. I'd choose the colon (or even a dash) here, and worry about the choice of zero punctuation. The lack of a capital (for 'when') and inverted commas might perturb some.

Comment: That's just punctuation; the important thing is what it's trying and failing to convey -- that in a direct quote one is imitating the speaker, and uses very different intonation (and maybe voice quality, too) than one uses in indirect speech, which is just another subordinate clause. The grammatical difference has to do with Subject-Auxiliary Inversion. Either one is OK -- one has the choice to quote or not to quote.